# How can I show a compass and a ruler in Beamer animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to show a ruler and a compass in my beamer animation same as the gif below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[dvipsnames,mathserif,fleqn]{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz,xparse}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \newcommand{\NodeAngle}[2]{%
        %\pgfextra{
            \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints%
                {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
                {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
                \global\let\MyAngle\pgfmathresult
        }%}

        % #1 premier point              ---- Distance entre 2 nodes ----
        % #2 second point
        % On récupère le résultat dans \MyDist
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\NodeDist}[2]{%
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}
                     {\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
        % no need to use a new dimen
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        % to convert from pt to cm
        \pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)/28.45274}
        \global\let\MyDist\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro
    }
    \makeatother

    % ######################
    %     Dessin crayon    #
    % ######################

    \newcommand{\Crayon}[1]{%
        \begin{scope}[scale=.7,#1]
        % Dessin de bois
        \fill[gray!60] (-.2,4.8) -- (.2,4.8)
                    -- (.2,.8) --(.1,.65)
                    -- (0,.8) -- (-.1,.66)
                    -- (-.2,.8) -- cycle ;
        \draw[color=white] (0,4.8) -- (0,.8 );
        \fill[black] (-.2,4.3) -- (0,4.27)
                    -- (.2,4.3) -- (.2,4.8) arc(30:150:0.23cm) ;

        % pointe taillée
        \fill[brown!50] (-.2,.8)
            -- (0,0) node[coordinate,pos=0.75](a){}
            -- (.2,.8) node[coordinate,pos=0.25](b){}
            -- (.1,.65) -- (0,.8) -- (-.1,.66) -- cycle;
        \fill[gray] (a) -- (0,0) -- (b) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    }

    \newcommand{\PointeCr}[1]{% pour le compas vu de haut
        \begin{scope}[scale=.7,#1]
        % pointe taillée
        \fill[brown!50] (-.2,.8)
            -- (0,0) node[coordinate,pos=0.75](a){}
            -- (.2,.8) node[coordinate,pos=0.25](b){}
            -- (.1,.65) -- (0,.8) -- (-.1,.66) -- cycle;
        \fill[gray] (a) -- (0,0) -- (b) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    }


    % ######################
    %   Dessin du compas   #
    % ######################

    \NewDocumentCommand{\Compas}{smm}{%

        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        % with *
        % keep distance between extemities
        }{%
        % without *
        % calulation of the distance between extremities
        \NodeDist{#2}{#3}
        }

        \NodeAngle{#2}{#3}

        \def\L{6} % taille des branches du compas

        % calcul de l'angle de l'ouverture
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleCP}{asin(\MyDist/(2*\L))}

        \begin{scope}[shift=(#2)]
        \begin{scope}[%
            join=round,
            rotate=\MyAngle,
            shift=(270-\AngleCP:-\L)
            ]

        % branche pointe sèche
        \draw[rotate=-\AngleCP,fill=gray!80]
            (0,0)--(0,-\L)--(-.2,-\L+.8)--(-.2,0)--cycle ;
        \draw[rotate=-\AngleCP,fill=gray!05]
            (0,-\L+.8)--(0,-\L)--(-.2,-\L+.8)--cycle ;

        % branche crayon
        \draw[rotate=\AngleCP,fill=gray!80]
            (0,0)--(0,-\L)--(.2,-\L+.8)--(.2,0)--cycle ;

        \begin{scope}[rotate=\AngleCP,shift={(0,-\L)}]
        \Crayon{rotate=-12}
        \draw[fill=gray!25] (\L/30,\L/5) circle (\L/36) ;
        \fill[gray!5] (\L/30,\L/5)
                -- ++(30:\L/36) arc (30:45:\L/36) -- cycle ;
        \fill[gray!5] (\L/30,\L/5)
                -- ++(210:\L/36) arc (210:225:\L/36) ;
        \filldraw (\L/30,\L/5) circle (.02) ;
        \end{scope}

        % haut du compas
        \draw[fill=gray!80] (-.1,0) rectangle (.1,.7) ;
        \draw[fill=gray!25] (0,0) circle (.25) ;
        \fill[gray!5] (0,0) -- (30:.25) arc (30:45:.25) -- cycle ;
        \fill[gray!5,rotate=180]
            (0,0) -- (30:.25) arc (30:45:.25) -- cycle ;
        \filldraw (0,0) circle (.05) ;
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }


    \NewDocumentCommand{\CompasH}{smm}{%

        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        % with *
        % keep distance between extemities
        }{%
        % without *
        % calulation of the distance between extremities
        \NodeDist{#2}{#3}
        }

        \NodeAngle{#2}{#3}

    \def\L{6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Scale}{\MyDist/2/\L}

    \begin{scope}[%
        join=round,
        shift=($(#2)!.5!(#3)$),
        rotate=\MyAngle]

    \begin{scope}[xscale=\Scale]
        % branche pointe sèche
        \draw[rotate=-90,fill=gray!80]
            (.1,\L-1) rectangle (-.1,-\L+1) ;
        \draw[rotate=-90,fill=gray!05]
            (.1,-\L+1)--(0,-\L)--(-.1,-\L+1)--cycle ;
    \end{scope}

    \draw[fill=gray!25,rounded corners=2pt]
        (-.4,-.14) rectangle(.4,.14) ;

    \draw[fill=gray!25,rounded corners=2pt]
        (-.3,-.14) rectangle(.3,.14) ;

    \begin{scope}[xscale=\Scale]

        \begin{scope}[shift={(\L,0)}]
            \clip (-1.4,-.17) rectangle (-12,.17) ;
            \Crayon{rotate=90,yscale=1.2}
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[shift={(\L,0)}]
            \clip (-1.4,-.17) rectangle (0.1,.17) ;
            \Crayon{rotate=90,yscale=2}
        \end{scope}

        \draw[draw=gray!50,
            ultra thin,
            fill=gray!15,
            rounded corners=2pt]
            (4.25,-.17) rectangle (4.85,.17) ;

        \draw[ultra thick,
            yshift=-.5pt,
            black!80,
            line cap=round]
            (4.35,-.17)--(4.75,-.17) ;
    \end{scope}

        \filldraw[gray!50!black] (0,0) circle (.08) ;
        \fill[black] (0,0) circle (.2pt) ;

    \end{scope}

    }

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (O) at (0:0);
    \coordinate (A) at (200:0);
    \coordinate (B) at (150:1.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (120:1.5);

    \coordinate (D) at (120:1.5);
    \coordinate (E) at (90:1.5);
    \coordinate (F) at (60:1.5);


    \draw[thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;

    \foreach \i/\lab in {A/below,B/below,C/above}
    {\node[inner sep=2pt,fill,circle,label=\lab:$\i$]at(\i){};}

    \onslide<1-1>{\draw[dashed,very thick] (A) arc [start angle=150, end angle=180, radius=1.5cm];}
    \onslide<1-1>{\Compas{A}{C}}
    \onslide<2-2>{\draw[dashed,very thick] (A) arc [start angle=150, end angle=210, radius=1.5cm];}
    \onslide<2-2>{\Compas{A}{D}}
    \onslide<3->{\draw[dashed,very thick] (A) arc [start angle=150, end angle=240, radius=1.5cm];}
    \onslide<3->{\Compas{A}{E}}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: You have gotten rather far, +1 for that. Unfortunately your code represents a rather wild mix of packages and usages, which reduces the number of users who may be able to help. Any chance you can kick out all these unused packages and these `\NewDocumentCommand`s in favor of `pic`s?

Comment: A PSTricks expert has made such an animation, visit [this link](http://pstricks.blogspot.com/2017/07/des-outils-pour-la-geometrie-avec.html).

Comment: thank you @Schrödinger'scat :D

Comment: thank you @OnlyTheParanoidSurvive  :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments